# Is there a way to change the SHELL program called by os.system()?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell, os.system

I’m in an embedded environment where`/bin/sh`doesn’t exist so when I call`posix.system()`or `os.system()`it always returns`-1`.
Because of that environment, the`subprocess`module isn’t available. I can’t create pipes too.

I’m using [ɴᴀᴄʟ as glibc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-glibc).

Setting the`SHELL`environment variable doesn’t seems to work *(it still tries to open`/bin/sh`)*.

So is there a way to change the shell process invoked by`os.system()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't change what shell `os.system()` uses, because that function makes a call to the [`system()` C function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), and that function has the shell hardcoded to `/bin/sh`.

Use the [`subprocess.call()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead, and set the `executable` argument to the shell you want to use:

```
subprocess.call("command", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

From the [`Popen()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (which underlies all `subprocess` functionality):

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If *args* is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.

and

> If `shell=True`, on Unix the *executable* argument specifies a replacement shell for the default `/bin/sh`.

If you can't use `subprocess` *and* you can't use pipes, you'd be limited to the [`os.spawn*()` functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnl); set *mode* to `os.P_WAIT` to wait for the exit code:

```
retval = os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, '/bin/bash', '-c', 'command')
```

Comment: except that I can use the`subprocess`module. I forgot to tell I use this as my libc https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-glibc

Comment: @user2284570: then you are entirely out of luck.

Comment: Except if there’s a pythonic way to issue system calls directly *(that is, without using a third party module or library)*. Is doing this impossible too ?

Comment: @user2284570: added the `os.spawn*()` functions. Lets hope for your sake those are implemented on your system. :-)

Comment: @user2284570: then you really are out of options entirely.

Comment: @user2284570: Thanks, but you don't need to point me to the Python documentation. Unless you are trying to tell me you are trying to run this on Google App Engine; I'd not even bother trying to get shell access on those servers. And the correct link in that case is the one for the [`posix` module](http://gae-pydoc.appspot.com/posix) instead.